# Overloading function in extension produces errors

Tags: swift

I tried to add append overload for Swift Array

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    func append<From>(from: [From], transformer: (From) -> [Element]) {
        from.forEach {
            self.append(contentsOf: transformer($0))
        }
    }
}
```

And it shows me compilation error: `Error:(47, 24) extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call`
it looks like I can't use other overloads of append in my own overload. It's really strange. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is misleading.  Your `append` function needs to be marked as `mutating`:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func append<From>(from: [From], transformer: (From) -> [Element]) {
        from.forEach {
            self.append(contentsOf: transformer($0))
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Alternate Implementation**

*(This might not be what you need, but it could help another user.)*

If you make your `transformer` to be `(From) -> Element`, you can simplify this to:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func append<From>(from: [From], transformer: (From) -> Element) {
        self.append(contentsOf: from.map(transformer))
    }
}
```

**Example call:**

```
var strings = ["a", "b", "c"]
strings.append(from: [1, 2, 3], transformer: String.init)
print(strings)  // prints ["a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: Mutating, thanks, that's what I need. I don't need this  transformer: (From) -> Element transformer, I need exactly this transformer: (From) -> [Element]. But thanks, you helped a lot